# Is there any way to replace nested for-in loops

Tags: ios, swift

In my code i have nested query to fetch data and for that i have to go last level to fetch that value. for that i have to run for loop 4 time. instead of that is there any way in realm function to decrease this loop and access time?

```
var tax = 0.0
for item in items {
    for menuItem in item.itemOrderMenu {
        for customize in menuItem.menuSetItems {
            for custom in customize.customizationItems where custom.isSelected {
                tax += custom.taxAmount
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is there a better approach to access nested data?

Comment: Are all of those types `Object` subclasses? Are you looking for a solution using Realm's `filter` and an `NSPredicate` for the query? If that's the case, you should [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve], specifically include all Realm model class definitions and declaration of `items`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a bunch of `flatMap`, followed by a `filter` and lastly a `reduce`:

```
let customisationItems = items.lazy.flatMap { $0.itemOrderMenu.lazy.flatMap { $0.menuSetItems.lazy.flatMap { $0.customisationItems } } }
let tax = es.filter { $0.isSelected }.reduce(0.0, { $0 + $1.taxAmount })
```

I don't think you can reduce the nesting of that anymore.

Comment: thanks you saved lot of time of mine for this issue :)

Comment: You should probably use `lazy` to avoid a multitude of intermediate arrays.